# open Chrome console when DOM ready and set viewport

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I am wondering if there is any way I can open Chrome console when the webpage is firstly loaded and set the viewport to a specific device (iPhone X), through a JavaScript code.

I had to do a test where I should only work on iPhone X viewport so I thought was nice if they can already see the console opened with the interested viewport active so they are going to check straight away my work instead of clicking cmd+alt+j and then set toggle device toolbar

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this to be true, but I'm guessing that might not be possible because it would infringe on the sandboxing principles that Chrome tabs are based on.   You are asking for system level control of the Chrome Browser UI, and there's a lot of effort put into not letting JS code do that because of malicious intent.

You could try using Electron to build an App that does this for you, however that may still have the sandbox boundary concern.

EDIT - You may also look into the Chrome extension architecture.   It allows you to implement code outside of the sandbox boundaries.   I'm not entirely hopeful that this would work, but it I do know that extensions allow you to control most of interface.

Comment: thanks Jocko, I will accept your answer if there won't be any others soon